# Can a subgradient always be found in polynomial time?

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

Given a convex function, under what conditions can we find a subgradient in polynomial time? There are easy examples such as $f$ being an supremum of a finite number of differentiable functions, but which regularity conditions must hold in general?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. The complexity of computing a subgradient---or even a standard derivative, for that matter---isn't just a function of the *mathematical* properties of the function, but also of *how it is described*. So for instance, even your example is incorrect: there is no guarantee that the supremum of a finite number of differentiable functions has a tractable subgradient, because there is no guarantee that the underlying derivatives can be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: For example, if I'm allowed to perform additions and multiplications, then $f(x)=x^2$ can be computed in a single operation, but $f(x)=e^x$ requires an infinite number of them. And given any finite set of acceptable "atomic" operations, surely there is a differentiable function that cannot be computed using a finite combination of them.

Comment: Very good points as usual, thank you. But essentially then, the only way of telling if a subgradient can be found in polynomial time is to present an algorithm that does so?

Comment: Yes, and I think that's true for standard gradients as well. I'm just not seeing the relationship between mathematical regularity and computational complexity.

Comment: Basically, I'm interested in the specific relationship between convexity and polynomial time solvability - apparently there is no general guarantee of equivalence. Was curious about if there existed any regularity conditions that would guarantee it.

Comment: Well, all of the analyses I have looked at consider complexity in terms of the number of iterations of the optimization algorithm. The complexity of any underlying derivative/subgradient calculations is assumed to be O(1).